# Access Cloud kit/Core Data entries inside Intents extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, sirishortcuts

I built an App using Core Data and Cloudkit. To access the data I used the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer:

```
   lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Tournaments")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    return container
}()
```

Now I want to add a Siri kit extension in order to add new Data to my App using Siri and Shortcuts. How can i access the Cloud Kit/Core Data Data from inside the Intents extension?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem using[this](https://medium.com/@manibatra23/sharing-data-using-core-data-ios-app-and-extension-fb0a176eaee9) tutorial using app groups